# Recorrer objeto ResultSet basado en una clase compuesta

Tags: java

A todos un buen día. Mi duda en esta oportunidad se genera a partir del siguiente método:

```
public static void listaRegistros(ResultSet rss, List<EnteComercial> lstEnteComercial) {
  try {
    while (rss.next()) {
      lstEnteComercial.add(new EnteComercial(
        rss.getDouble("idEnteComercial"), rss.getString("razonSocial"),
        rss.getDouble("telefono"), rss.getString("direccion"),
        rss.getString("idTipoEmpe"), // Error de conversión.
        rss.getString("idTipoRegimen") // Error de conversión.
      ));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
}
```

El método es el clásico encargado de almacenar el resultado de una consulta a la base de datos de una tabla con los campos mencionados en el while(), en una lista, en este caso de tipo "EnteComercial".

La estructura de la clase "EnteComercial" incorpora dos atributos que son de tipo "TipoEnte" y "TipoRegimen" que la "componen". Estas dos clases a su vez, cuentan con sendos atributos de tipo String, que se son la parte de ellas por composición asociadas a la clase "EnteComercial" (-idTipoEnte- y -idTipoRegimen- respectivamente).

```
public class EnteComercial {
  private double idEnteComercial, telefono;
  private String razonSocial, direccion;
  private TipoEnte tipoEnte;
  private TipoRegimen tipoRegimen;

  // Constructor de la clase a partir del cual se estructura la lista con
  // los datos resultantes de la consulta a la base da datos.
  public EnteComercial(double idEnteComercial, String razonSocial, double telefono,
      String direccion, TipoEnte tipoEnte, TipoRegimen tipoRegimen)
  {
    this.idEnteComercial = idEnteComercial;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.tipoEnte = tipoEnte;
    this.tipoRegimen = tipoRegimen;
  }
  ...
}

public class TipoEnte {
  private String idTipoEnte, nombreTipoEnte;
  ...
}

public class TipoRegimen {
  private String idTipoRegimen, nombreRegimen;
  ...
}
```

Por ser tipos desconocidos para Java rss.getString("idTipoEnte") y rss.getString("idTipoRegimen") producen un error de tipos:

> "**incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TipoEnte**"

y

> "**incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TipoRegimen**"

respectivamente.

Aunque la única figura que encuentro para "esquivar" el error, es implementar en la clase "EnteComercial" un nuevo constructor donde los parámetros (... TipoEnte tipoEnte, TipoRegimen tipoRegimen) sean reemplazados por (... String tipoEnte, String tipoRegimen) para que el método listaRegistros(...) opere sin problemas. Esto sin contar que además se deben declarar los dos campos nuevos de tipo String, lo cual desnaturaliza la clase y la vuelve confusa.

Esto me produce la incertidumbre: ¿Siempre que se construyan clases compuestas de otras clases, la forma para construir este tipo de consultas como la diseñada en el método "listaRegistros" es el que menciono como solución, o existen recursos más eficaces, claros y elegantes para llegar a la solución?

He intentado aplicar la solución que amablemente me ha sugerido abajo Diego, pero con el inconveniente que "la información de las clases que componen la clase compuesta", no queda almacenada en la lista que toma los datos del objeto ResultSet. Por ello, haré un análisis con estas dos clases nuevas, presentando la mayor parte del ciclo que se quiere completar junto al error que lo impide.

Se supondrá que hay dos clases, la primera es la clase -Auto- con dos atributos, la placa y la marca del respectivo auto: "placaAuto" y "marcaAuto". Hay también una segunda clase -Conductor- cuyos atributos son su identificación, su nombre y la placa del auto que puede conducir: "idConductor", "nombreConductor" y "placaAuto". Este ultimo atributo se obtiene por composición de la clase -Auto- quedando así configuradas las clases que cuentan con sus respectivos gets y sets pero no se muestran para mayor brevedad.

```
public class Auto {
  private String placaAuto, marcaAuto;

  public Auto() {  }

  public Auto(String placaAuto, String marcaAuto) {
    this.placaAuto = placaAuto;
    this.marcaAuto = marcaAuto;
  }
  /* gets and sets respectivos ... */
}
```

La segunda clase -Conductor- se compone también de la clase -Auto- así:

```
public class Conductor {
  private double idConductor;
  private String nombreConductor;
  private Auto auto;

  public Conductor() {  }

  public Conductor(double idConductor, String nombreConductor, Auto auto) {
    this.idConductor = idConductor;
    this.nombreConductor = nombreConductor;
    this.auto = auto;
  }
  /* gets and sets respectivos ... */
}
```

Las base de datos de la aplicación cuenta con las tablas -auto- con los campos "placa" y "marcaAuto". La tabla -conductor- con los campos "idConductor", "nombreConductor" y "placaAuto" respectivamente.

Al asignar y leer los atributos de la clase -Conductor- para almacenarla en la base de datos, se hace de la manera tradicional: **conductor.getIdConductor**, etc. Para la placa que hace parte de la clase -Auto- se hace así:

> **conductor.getAuto.getPlaca()** y **conductor.getAuto.setPlaca()**

El método encargado de presentar la información por pantalla es más o menos así:

```
public static void mostrarConductores(List<Conductor> lsConductor) {
  System.out.println("LISTADO DE CONDUCTORES");
  for (Conductor conductor: lsConductor) {
    System.out.println("__________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Identificación  Nombre Conductor  Placa");
    System.out.println("==================================================================");
    System.out.printf("%14.0f  %-20s  %-8s\n", conductor.getIdConductor(),
          conductor.getNombreConductor(), conductor.getAuto.getPlaca());
  }
}
```

Y la lista "lsConductor" que llega como parámetro al método "mostrarConductores", es la que se quiere cargar en el método "lsListaConductores" que presento abajo, el cual recibe como parámetro adicional, un objeto "rss" de tipo ResultSet con la consulta a la base de datos "Select * From Conductor". En dicho objeto, quedan almacenados los campos (idConductor, nombreConductor y placa). Estos resultados posteriormente, se quieren trasladar debidamente formateados, a una lista tipo "Conductor" como se aprecia a continuación:

```
public static void lsListaConductores(ResultSet rss, List<Conductor> lsConductor) {
  Auto auto;

  try {
    while (rss.next()) {
      auto = new Auto();

      lsConductor.add(new Conductor(
            rss.getDouble("idConductor"),
            rss.getString("nombreConductor"),
            auto
      ));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error en el reporte: " + e);
  }
}
```

Noto en esta solución, que el objeto "auto" no se relaciona con el objeto ResultSet, motivo por el cual supongo, la información de la placa no se muestra en el informe al no quedar registrada en la lista. Sin embargo, sí quedan registrados y se pueden ver los valores de los campos "idConductor" y "nombreConductor", por ser estos cargados directamente desde el objeto ResultSet como se aprecia en el método "lsListaConductores".

Aunque he intentado asociar el objeto ResultSet con algunos de sus varios métodos con el objeto "auto" y capturar la información de la placa, no he logrado consolidar el procedimiento correcto que no arroje errores o que recupere la información de la consulta debidamente.

Tengo la sospecha, que la solución podría ser con el empleo del método **getObject** de ResultSet, pero ignoro si esto carece de fundamentos.

Gracias por sus comentarios y colaboración.

Comment: La  pregunta no es clara, no sé si lo que quieres es mapear los resultados de la consulta en tu clase `EnteComercial`... En cuanto al `ResultSet`, con método como `getString` tú puedes acceder a valores que se encuentren en el `SELECT`. O sea, que si la SQL es: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM ...`, en los getter del `ResultSet`  tú puedes usar `rs.getString('col1')` o `rs.getString('col2')`

Comment: El código presenta una lista tipo "EnteComercial" cuyos atributos se presentan más abajo. El select a la tabla, carga los datos a un objeto ResultSet con los valores asociados a los campos mencionados.

Comment: Se busca cargar dichos datos a la lista después de la consulta, pero se obtiene el error mencionado. ¿Cómo evitar el mencionado error? es la cuestión. Nótese que si los atributos "tipoEnte" y "tipoAtributo" fueran de tipo String, el método no presentaría error alguno, por contar estos con el método getString para recuperar su valor. Sin embargo, hay que notar que los tipos de datos son de un tipo, para el cual java no cuenta con un método concreto, pues la estructura de datos a incorporar en la lista, obedece al constructor de la clase "EnteComercial".

Comment: Dejo copia del constructor de la clase "EnteComercial": public EnteComercial(double idEnteComercial, String razonSocial, double telefono, String direccion, TipoEnte tipoEnte, TipoRegimen tipoRegimen) { this.idEnteComercial = idEnteComercial ... this.tipoEnte = tipoEnte, this.tipoRegimen = tipoRegimen }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y gracias a Diego Hernandez, esta es la solución a la inquietud planteada desde un principio.

```
/**
 * Método que carga en una lista tipo "EnteComercial" la información consultada
 * en la base de datos, almacenada en el objeto rss.
 */
public static void listaRegistros(ResultSet rss, List<EnteComercial> lstEnteComercial) {
  try {
    while (rss.next()) { // Recorrido de la información consultada.
      // Instanciación de las clases que componen la clase "EnteComercial"
      TipoEnte tipoEnte = new TipoEnte();
      TipoRegimen tipoRegimen = new TipoRegimen();

      // Alimenta los atributos de las clases que componen la clase compuesta consultada
      tipoEnte.setIdTipoEnte(rss.getString("idTipoEnte"));
      tipoRegimen.setIdTipoRegimen(rss.getStrint("idTipoRegimen"));

      // Anexa a la lista tipo "EnteComercial" el registro actual del objeto rss
      lstEnteComercial.add(new EnteComercial(
        rss.getDouble("idEnteComercial"), rss.getString("razonSocial"),
        rss.getDouble("telefono"), rss.getString("direccion"),
        TipoEnte, TipoRegimen
      ));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
}
```

Así, la información viaja completa en la lista que se empleará a posteriori para generar un reporte.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
public static void listaRegistros(ResultSet rss, List<EnteComercial> lstEnteComercial) {
  try {

     TipoRegimen regimen;
     TipoEnte ente;

     while (rss.next()) {

      ente = new TipoEnte();
      ente.setIdTipoRegimen(rss.getString("idTipoEmpe"));

      regimen = new regimen();
      regimen.serIdTipoRegimen(rss.getString("idTipoRegimen"));

      lstEnteComercial.add(new EnteComercial(
        rss.getDouble("idEnteComercial"), rss.getString("razonSocial"),
        rss.getDouble("telefono"), rss.getString("direccion"),
        ente, 
        regimen
      ));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
}
```

Esto suponiendo que las clases tienen sus respectivos get y set.
Puede de igual forma crear los objetos "TipoRegimen" y  "TipoEnte" en el constructor del "Entecomercial" cuando lo estas creando para agregarlo a la lista.

Comment: Gracias Diego por la solución que evita los errores mencionados. El problema ahora, es a la hora de querer leer la información almacenada en la lista, pues esta incorpora además de los datos de la consulta a la base de datos, dos objetos: "TipoRegimen" y "TipoEnte". Estos a la hora de leerse de la siguiente forma: ** ente.getTipoEnte().getIdTipoEnte() ** reporta un valor "null". Creo yo, porque a la hora de almacenar la información en el While, se hace alusión al objeto "TipoEnte", pero no al valor del campo que lo asocia con la clase "EnteComercial" es decir: ente.idTipoEnte de tipo String.

Comment: Al intentar cambiar "ente" por "ente.getIdTipoEnte" y "regimen" por "regimen.getIdTipoRegimen", el error se invierte respecto al anterior mostrando: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TipoEnte" y en ese bucle de errores de tipo, no es posible recuperar la información de la consulta, atendiendo estrictamente la estructura de composición de la clase "EnteComercial". Gracias por cualquier sugerencia para superar este error de forma que he encontrado a la hora de trabajar con clases compuestas en Java.

Comment: Has revisado si realmente estas obteniendo los datos que necesitas cuando haces la consulta.Déjame ver el código completo que estas utilizando, para poder obtener los datos de la lista.

Comment: Gracias Diego. Voy a colocar como una ampliación del problema, una analogía con otras dos clases que siguen exactamente el mismo patrón, y presentan igual mensaje de error al que presentan las clases anteriores, ampliando el contexto de la aplicación. Esto por temas de sencillez, por ser las clases del nuevo ejemplo, más sencillas en su definición y me permite plantear el problema, con nueva argumentación.

Comment: Aclaro que el error no se trata de un mensaje en esta ocasión, se trata de la información obtenida, que para el caso, no se logra recuperar en su totalidad como se explica. Arriba ya he dejado las ampliaciones respectivas, espero sean lo suficientemente didácticas.

Comment: @CharlieBrown He revisado tu código y el problema es que no almacenas los datos necesarios en la propiedad del objeto **auto**,prueba hacer esto en el método **lsListaConductores()** : `auto.setPlacaAuto(rss.getString("placaauto"));`

Comment: Diego Gracias por colaborar, pero la solución que planteas es justamente la fuente del error con que se inició el problema. Las listas, al menos la del problema que planteo, se forman a partir de la estructura de los constructores asociados a la tabla de base de datos, de la clase que se quiere consultar. La clase que menciono, no tiene entre los parámetros del constructor, un atributo "String" de nombre "placaAuto", por ende, el probar con tu sugerencia genera un error de tipos: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Auto".

Comment: Esto debido a que la clase cuenta con una composición que no apunta directamente a una propiedad de tipo String, sino que lo hace indirectamente a través de la clase Auto, que si tiene un atributo "String" denominado "placaAuto", es decir, mediante la forma conductor.getAuto.getPlacaAuto().

Comment: Aunque la consulta en el objeto ResultSet ignora la composición de clases de de la aplicación, ya que ella tiene almacenados tres campos: double, String, String, para leer estos datos, se debe hacer apoyándose como ya señale, basados en la estructura del constructor de la clase "Conductor" que no es: double, String, String, sino: double, String, Auto. Esto genera la necesidad de leer un tipo para el cual ResultSet no dispone de un método directo, pero seguramente, mediante algún mecanismo indirecto, creo se puede lograr, es decir, una forma de leer objetos ResulSet con clases compuestas.

Comment: Diego, tenías razón. Era cuestión de aplicar el valor al atributo del objeto que compone la clase consultada, previamente a guardarlo como objeto en la lista con los demás valores obtenidos de la lectura. Deje abajo, gracias a tu colaboración, la respuesta a la inquietud inicial.